# Regex replace all matched tokens with lowercase

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following html text snippet

```
  <th>Member name:</th>
  <td>$$FULLNAME$$</td>
  <th>Club:</th>
  <td>$$ClubName$$</td>
  <th>Business Category:</th>
  <td>$$SubCategory$$</td>
```

I am trying to replace all the tokens e.g. `$$FULLNAME$$` becomes `$$fullname$$` using C#, the output should be

```
  <th>Member name:</th>
  <td>$$fullname$$</td>
  <th>Club:</th>
  <td>$$clubname$$</td>
  <th>Business Category:</th>
  <td>$$subcategory$$</td>
```

I have come up with this which does not work correctly as the `\L`is not converting the matches to lowercase

```
public static string TokenReplacer(string value)
{
    var pattern = Regex.Escape("$$") + "(.*?)" + Regex.Escape("$$");
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    return regex.Replace(value, Regex.Unescape("$$$$") + @"\L$1" + Regex.Unescape("$$$$"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\$\$.+?\$\$", m => m.Value.ToLower());
```

Comment: thanks, got myself in a right pickle :) will accept as soon as I can